# sails.js date picker isn't saving selected value

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, sails.js

I'm trying to add a date field to an edit page and while the date picker is working, and a date can be selected, when the form is saved, the field remains empty in the database.

Can anyone tell me how to capture the date from the date picker in sails.js?

.ejs file:

```
<form action="/user/update/<%= user.id %>" method="POST" class="form-signin">
<h2>Update User Information</h2>

First Name:&nbsp;<input value="<%= user.first_name %>" name="first_name" type="text" class="form-control"/>
Last Name:&nbsp;<input value="<%= user.last_name %>" name="last_name" type="text" class="form-control"/>
Title:&nbsp;<input value="<%= user.title %>" name="title" type="text" class="form-control"/>
Username:&nbsp;<input value="<%= user.username %>" name="username" type="text" class="form-control"/>
Email:&nbsp;<input value="<%= user.email %>" name="email" type="text" class="form-control"/>
Date of Birth:&nbsp;<input value="<%= user.dob %>" name="dob" type="date" class="form-control"/>
Gender:&nbsp;<input value="<%= user.gender %>" name="gender" type="text" class="form-control">
Zip Code:<input value="<%= user.zip_code %>" name="zip_code" type="text" class="form-control">
Activation Date:<input value="<%= user.activation_date %>" name="activation_date" type="date" class="form-control"/>
Expiration Date:<input value="<%= user.expiration_date%>" name="expiration_date" type="date"  class="form-control"/>
Admin:&nbsp;<input value="<%= user.admin %>" name="admin" type="text" class="form-control"/>
<input type="submit" value="Proceed" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"/>
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= _csrf %>" />
```

Here is the code from the User controller:

```
    edit: function(req, res, next) {
    User.findOne(req.param('id'), function foundUser(err, user) {
        if(err) return next(err);
        if(!user) return next('user doesn\'t exist.');

        res.view({
            user: user
        });
    });
},

update: function(req, res, next) {
    User.update(req.param('id'), req.params.all(), function userUpdated(err,user){

        if(err) {
            return res.redirect('user/edit' + req.param('id'));
        }

        res.redirect('/user/show/' + req.param('id'));
    });
},
```

Comment: You'll have to post the code that handles the `/user/update/:id` action.  It would also help if you showed the data that you're getting server-side, since we have no idea what date picker you're using and what format it sends.

Comment: It appears that the form is submitting the dates to the database, but when the record is opened for editing again, the fields are not set to the values in the database.  They just show the 'YY/MM/YY' default.

Comment: Sorry, it's really impossible to help without you posting any server-side code, and without knowing what actual data is being posted.

Comment: My bad.  I've added the code that calls the edit form and the update function that gets called from the edit form.  Please let me know if I"m missing any code you need to see.  Thanks in adavance for your help!

Comment: Ok, now, what data is being posted?  Try putting a `console.log(req.param('dob'))` in your update function to see.

Answer (score 0):

When using the date input type you need to set the value to a proper [RFC339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) representation. What you get back from Sails will be a date that has had `toString()` called on it.

You should be able to format the dates in the ejs file when setting the value like so:

```
<% var dob = (new Date(d)).toISOString().slice(0,10) %>    
Date of Birth:&nbsp;<input value="<%= dob %>" name="dob" type="date" class="form-control"/>
```